# Finding the most common pair, trio, etc. in a list of 20 random numbers, played 100 times

Tags: python, math, random, combinations

So I have a CSV with 100 rows, 20 numbers on each row separated with a comma as such:

```
23, 52, 63, 76, 23, 45, ...
39, 52, 83, 33, 35, 23, ...
etc.
```

I would like to write an algorithm that finds all the different combinations of a pair, and list the amount of times it has occurred, and do the same for a trio, for a quad, etc.

Obviously for each line there would be a lot of combinations (since order wouldn't matter)

This would be the answer for every line

[image]

So 15 combinations per line.. now I can only imagine how many there would be if it were 20 instead of 6, but let's not worry about that for now.

Since there are 15, I wouldn't want the program to show me every single combination, only those whose "count" is higher than 1, "count" being the number of times they have occurred.

So if I ran the program for just those two lines above, for 6 numbers instead of 20, the program would return

```
23, 52: 2
```

See how only the pair that occurred more than once is shown, that's what I'd like to do, but that would be easy, just not show if the count is equal to 1.

Anyway, how would I get started on creating this algorithm? I don't know where to start, I guess I would begin by scraping every line, and getting every pair, but how would I do this?

Thank you in advance, and no doubt I will keep hacking at this problem, if I find the solution I will post it (as well as the code). Thank you again.

Comment: Are the pairs to be considered line by line, or across all lines?

Comment: Also, I see a total of 3 pairs of (23, 52) in the above lines...

Comment: in general this sounds like frequent set mining.

Comment: @Rishav You're right, I missed that :P And yes, line by line, every time the pair occurs and +1 is added to the count

Comment: To begin you can get all pairs of one line with 
for i in range(n-1):
 for j in range(i+1,n):
  print(line[i],line[j])

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Code is annotated inline.

```
import itertools

lines = [[23, 52, 63, 76, 23, 45],
         [39, 52, 83, 33, 35, 23]]

# This set will store the unique elements
# across all lines
uniq = set()

# This list will hold a dict for each line
# These dicts will contain the frequency
# of each unique number in that line

freq = [{} for _ in range(len(lines))]
for index, line in enumerate(lines):
    for j in line:

        freq[index][j] = freq[index].get(j, 0) + 1
        uniq.add(j)

# This will store the frequency of each possible pair
counter = {}

# There will be k * (k - 1) / 2 combinations,
# where k is the number of unique pairs

for i in itertools.combinations(uniq, 2):
    for j in range(len(lines)):

        freq1 = freq[j].get(i[0], 0)
        freq2 = freq[j].get(i[1], 0)

        # Multiplying frequencies gives us the number
        # of pairs with these numbers in this line

        counter[i] = counter.get(i, 0) + (freq1 * freq2)

# Performs a descending sort on all pairs
sol = sorted(counter.items(), key=lambda value: value[1], reverse=True)
print(sol)
```

Output:

```
   [((52, 23), 3), ((45, 23), 2), ((23, 63), 2), ((76, 23), 2), ((33, 35), 1),
    ((76, 45), 1), ((52, 63), 1), ((39, 83), 1), ((76, 52), 1), ((45, 52), 1),
    ((35, 39), 1), ((39, 23), 1), ((33, 52), 1), ((39, 52), 1), ((33, 23), 1),
    ((35, 23), 1), ((35, 52), 1), ((76, 63), 1), ((33, 83), 1), ((35, 83), 1),
    ((33, 39), 1), ((83, 23), 1), ((45, 63), 1), ((83, 52), 1), ((83, 63), 0),
    ((35, 76), 0), ((33, 76), 0), ((35, 45), 0), ((33, 45), 0), ((45, 83), 0),
    ((39, 63), 0), ((33, 63), 0), ((39, 76), 0), ((39, 45), 0), ((76, 83), 0),
    ((35, 63), 0)]
```

*Beware!* This algorithm will run in ~ O(n^4) if the list consists mostly of unique values.

EDIT: Here is another version that should perform better (it maintains the `uniq` set for every line, and hence avoids zero-size combinations).

```
import functools
import itertools
import operator

lines = [[23, 52, 63, 76, 23, 45],
         [39, 52, 83, 33, 35, 23]]

# Set this variable before use!
permlength = 2

uniq = [set() for _ in range(len(lines))]
freq = [{} for _ in range(len(lines))]

for index, line in enumerate(lines):
    for j in line:
        freq[index][j] = freq[index].get(j, 0) + 1
        uniq[index].add(j)

counter = {}

print("Total number of lines: {}".format(len(lines)))

for i in range(len(lines)):
    print("Line {}...".format(i + 1))

    for j in itertools.combinations(uniq[i], permlength):

        freqp = [freq[i].get(j[x], 0) for x in range(permlength)]
        counter[j] = counter.get(j, 0) + functools.reduce(operator.mul, freqp)

sol = sorted(counter.items(), key=lambda value: value[1], reverse=True)

print(sol)
```

Output:

```
[((52, 23), 3), ((45, 23), 2), ((63, 23), 2), ((76, 23), 2), ((76, 52), 1),
 ((76, 45), 1), ((52, 63), 1), ((39, 83), 1), ((35, 39), 1), ((45, 52), 1),
 ((33, 52), 1), ((39, 52), 1), ((33, 23), 1), ((35, 23), 1), ((35, 52), 1),
 ((39, 23), 1), ((76, 63), 1), ((33, 83), 1), ((33, 39), 1), ((83, 23), 1),
 ((45, 63), 1), ((83, 52), 1), ((33, 35), 1), ((35, 83), 1)]
```

Comment: This is perfect, I am very grateful, thank you. Problem is, my macbook pro  16GB ram sketches out when there are more than 30 lines of lists with 20 numbers, I don't mind the program taking a long time, but how could I make it so it doesn't give me the wheel of death?

Comment: Would it make it easier if I only printed the pairs with more than 1 occurrence ?

Comment: Err, could you give me your input from `print(lines)` in a paste? I’ll ponder over it.

Comment: Ok, well, it's a lot.. also I'm using the substring [1:21] from each line, I'll post my code too.

Comment: I have 1,800 lines of numbers, but I wasn't able to paste more than 250 without my browser freezing, so I just pasted a portion

Comment: I think I fixed the problem by just looping through "sol" and printing every tuple individually, works perfectly now, thank you.

Comment: Yes, it worked when I ran it on the terminal, the python IDE is crap :P

Comment: How could I edit to only add to sol tuples with the count above 1

Comment: There is no way to do it in the middle of the loops. You have to filter out the keys from `sol` which have a value of 1, use a `filter` statement, or a simple loop.

Comment: Ok that worked, thank you :) Getting the combinations of 10 numbers is taking extremely long, is it just because it's highly unlikely and the program is reading every line to make sure?

Comment: @SamirChahine No, it’s just because the number of combinations increases. It’s 9690000 for combinations of length 6, and increases drastically for an increase of 1 length.

Comment: @SamirChahine sorry there was a mistake in my code for permutations of length greater than 2! Please see my edit again :) Sorry